# ASP.NET Identity Cookie not being set on localhost with different ports

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity

**I have two applications (.NET 7 with Angular), both on localhost but different ports**

App 1: This is a shared web API and it acts as a single sign on point for my other application.
App 2: This is the main application but it makes calls to app 1's API to log in.

Both apps use the **ASP.NET Core with Angular** template provided by visual studio.

**GOAL**: Users can go to App 2 and start a login request by entering their username and password. Once they click login those credentials are sent to app 1 to handle authentication and then app 1 sends an authentication cookie

---

**MY ISSUE:** The login request from app 2 to app 1 works and the user data is returned in app 2 and the authentication cookie is sent. However, the Set-Cookie header is not actually saving the cookie to the browser, specifically for localhost, so the user does not get authenticated. This same request in Postman works and the cookie is saved to both apps and the user gets authenticated.

---

**WHAT I THINK IS HAPPENING:** I think this may have something to do with the way chrome handles the special domain localhost. I can get this exact same request to work on Postman with no flaws. The apps are on different ports: app 1: https://localhost:44465 and app2: https://localhost:5000. I have read a decent amount of articles online saying that because they are on different ports chrome prevents the cookie from being shared.

**APP 1 Redacted Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

string? envRaw = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
string env = envRaw is null ? "Development" : envRaw;

var Config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("SHARED DIRECTORY"))
    .SetApplicationName("APP_NAME")
    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(7));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
}).AddIdentityCookies();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "APP_NAME";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.Cookie.Domain = null;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;

    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
        {
            var isApiCall = ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api");
            var hasOkStatus = ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            if (isApiCall && hasOkStatus)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        },
        // Do not redirect to /AccessDenied for forbidden API call; return Forbidden status code instead.
        OnRedirectToAccessDenied = ctx =>
        {
            var isApiCall = ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api");
            var hasOkStatus = ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            if (isApiCall && hasOkStatus)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    };
}); 

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
).RequireCors("CorsPolicy");

app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

**APP 2  Redacted Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
    )
);


// ASP.Net Autentication
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("SHARED DIRECTORY"))
    .SetApplicationName("APP_NAME")
    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(7));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
}).AddIdentityCookies();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "APP_NAME";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.Cookie.Domain = null;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;

    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
        {
            var isApiCall = ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api");
            var hasOkStatus = ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            if (isApiCall && hasOkStatus)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        },
        OnRedirectToAccessDenied = ctx =>
        {
            var isApiCall = ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api");
            var hasOkStatus = ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            if (isApiCall && hasOkStatus)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();
var cookiePathBase = builder.Configuration["App:CookiePathBase"];
app.UsePathBase(cookiePathBase);

app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.PathBase = new PathString(cookiePathBase);
    return next();
});


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii6oY.png)
Picture of request from app2 to app1 returning a 200 OK
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMpne.png)
Picture of authentication cookie included in the 200 OK response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20vBx.png)
Cookie being properly set in Postman

I have tried almost everything that I can find online. So here is a list of things I have tried and none of them changed anything:

- Specifying the Cookie Domain to be "localhost", null, "", and omitted it completely
- I set the cookie options to be SameSite=None and the Secure policy as Always. I also tried Lax and strict SameSite modes
- I tried proxying the request to localhost:44465 as localhost:5000 using proxy.conf.js in hopes this bypass cross site cookies
- Set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to be specific ports instead of the wildcard value (*)
- Set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to be true
- Set the Cookie to be HttpOnly and gave it an expiration date other than session
- Changed the cookie name in each app to be unique
- Tried Chrome Extension to allows CORS

None of these produced any results. My next attempt is going to be configuring IIS hosts to have subdomains of localhost to mirror the production environment ex.) app1.localhost and app2.localhost.

Looking forward to hearing your guys' suggestions!

Comment: APP2 has to set that session cookie.  Cookies set from APP1 (localhosts with different ports are considered different domains) will not be sent with requests going to APP2.  The samesite attribute doesn't affect that at all.  (that has to do with origin of the request... not whether the request destination matches the domain the cookie was set from)  There are also CORS rules that a browser enforces.  Postman has no such restrictions on cross-origin requests.  (anyway you can verify the cookies were set by sending the browser to APP1's URL.  Then check dev-tools for the cookie.)